# Symfony reload service from containerInterface with autowiring

Tags: symfony, service, autowired

Is it possible to reload and autowire a service?

I have a provider class that uses a number of services, these services use autowired configuration loaded from the database.

Looping through the list of providers (with different configuration in DB) results in the same class when I load the service via the containerInterface:

```
$objSearchProvider = $this->objContainer->get(
   $objService->getProvider()->getSearch()
);
```

The __constructor for the provider is only called the first time in the loop cause it is the same class.

I know there is **$this->objContainer->reset()** function, but this does not seem to re-autowire the configuration.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define your services as not shared if you need a new instance of them every time

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html